# Function.prototype.propertyname === Object.propertyname is true?

Tags: javascript

In trying to better understand the prototype behind javascript, I have stumbled upon the following, which I am unable to make sense of so far.

I understand that functions are a first class object, but I don't get why Object gets this property after setting the property on Function.prototype

```
Function.prototype.foo = 'bar';

Object.foo // Object now has this property and returns 'bar'

Object.foo === Function.prototype.foo // returns true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object` is a function, `typeof Object == 'function'` is true. So you assign a property of `Function.prototype`, it will let the `Object` has the property also. (in the property chain.)

Comment: And here i thought Object was an object. This clears it up, thank you!

Comment: @ChrisM: `Object` *is* an object. `Object instanceof Object; // true` But more specifically, it's a `Function` object. `Object instanceof Function; // true`. In JavaScript, functions are objects.

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken Function.prototype is a prototype for all inherited objects. Because you set `Function.prototype.foo = 'bar';` all objects inherit the `foo` property. That is why the third line of code returns true.

Comment: That's not quite right. `Function.prototype` is a prototype for all `Function` objects, not all objects. Only functions will inherit the `foo` property.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `Object` and `Function` objects share the same internal `[[Prototype]]` property.

As Ecma-262 says:

> The value of the internal [[Prototype]] property of the Function prototype object is the Object prototype object.

So if you add any property to the `Function`'s prototype, that property will be accessible through the `Object` object too, and vice versa.

If you want to understand it deeply, I'd suggest you to take a look at the **[Ecma-262 Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The following references might help: [Properties of the Object Constructor](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.3), [Properties of the Function Prototype Object](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4)